# lines on quintic del Pezzo 3-fold of degree 5

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The quintic del Pezzo $3$-fold $V(5)$ of degree $5$  is defined as the intersection of  $Grass(2,5)$ and a codimension $3$ linear subspace. I would like to show the following:

**For every point $p$ in $V(5)$ there is a line contained in $V(5)$ not passing through $p$.**

I know that $\operatorname{Gr}(2,5)$ is defined by $5$ quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^9$, thus we can view $V(5)$ as defined by $5$ quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^6$. Now given a point $p=[1,0,\dots,0]$, write the five quadrics as $$Q_i= q_{i,2}(x_1,\dots, x_n)+ x_0 q_{i,1}(x_1,\dots, x_n),$$ where $q_{i,k}$ is homogeneous of degree $k$. There is  a line contained in $V(5)$ passing through $p$ if and only if the $\{q_{i,2},q_{i,1}: i=1,2,3,4,5\}$ have a common zero in $\mathbb{P}^5$. Indeed, for a common zero $[a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n]$, the line joining $p$ and $[a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n]$ is contained in $V(5)$. Since the quadrics are linearly independent, the dimension of the subset defined by these $10$ equations is $\leq0$ which means there are only finitely many lines in $V(5)$ passing through a given point. I'm thinking whether the number of lines on $V(5)$ is finite or infinite so that I can compare the number of lines to get a line not passing through $p$. How to determine the number of lines on $V(5)$? Or is there a better approach to this question?

Comment: Just an extra comment: the five quadrics you are mentioning are way non general by obvious reasons. They are given by the 4-Pfaffians of the 5x5 skew matrix with the linear form $x_{i,j}$ at the $(i,j)$ entry. This is not directly connected to the question (which Sasha already solved), but might be relevant if you keep working with this particular variety.

Comment: @Enrico $V(5)$ can be obtained as the intersection of $Gr(2,5)$ with  $3$ hyperplanes in general position. Which hyperplanes should they be?

Comment: @L.X in this case you should be safe by picking three of $x_{i,j}+x_{k,l}$ (with $i \neq j \neq k \neq l$, all five indexes involved and appropriate different coefficients).

Comment: @Enrico You mean picking the hyperplanes in this way define the same variety V5?

Comment: With these choices (if you pick the coefficients general enough) the correspondent variety will be a smooth, generic example of $V_5$

Comment: @L.X by the way, this might help https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323095/construction-of-fano-threefold-of-degree-5-and-its-defining-equations/323099#323099

Comment: @Enrico Thanks, if I take $x_{12}=x_{34}$, $x_{13}=x_{45}$, $x_{23}=x_{15}$, then by a calculation I get two nonintersecting lines: one joining $( x_{14}=1,x_{ij}=0)$ and $( x_{12}=1,x_{ij}=0)$, the other joining $( x_{24}=1,x_{ij}=0)$ and $( x_{25}=1,x_{ij}=0)$. This should solve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be the quintic del Pezzo 3-fold. The Hilbert scheme of lines on $X$ is 2-dimensional (this follows easily from deformation theory). If there is a point $p \in X$ such that every line passes through $p$, then $X$ is a cone with vertex $p$,
hence either $X$ is singular at $p$, or $X \cong \mathbb{P}^3$. But, of course, neither of these is true.

Comment: I don't know what a Hilbert scheme is. Would you mind giving me some references?

Comment: Is there a way to know the number of lines on $V(5)$?

Comment: What do you mean? It is infinite of course, read Sasha's answer.

Comment: The Hilbert scheme is the natural way to parameterize subschemes of a fixed scheme (e.g., of the quintic del Pezzo 3-fold) of given type (e.g., of lines). The references are Grothendieck's FGA (original), or "FGA explained" (recent). The Hilbert scheme of lines on the quintic del Pezzo 3-fold is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: @abx Do you know the lines are infinite without knowing the Hilbert scheme is $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: Yes. For instance a general hyperplane section contains some lines.

Comment: @abx Ok, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by ''a general hyperplane section contains some lines''. I would do it by constructing an incidence correspondence and show that the subvariety in $\operatorname{Grass}(2,6)$ parametrising lines on $V(5)$  has dimension $\geq 2$ (which is consistent with the fact that the Hilbert scheme is $\mathbb{P}^2$). Plus my argument in the question has shown that there are finitely many lines passing through a given point. So this solves this question in an elementary way.

Comment: A general hyperplane section is a quintic del Pezzo surface. It is well known that it contains 10 lines.

Comment: for Hilbert schemes, see also Eisenbud & Harris, "Schemes: the language of modern algebraic geometry" (1992) and Nakajima, "Lectures on Hilbert schemes of points of surfaces" (1991).

Answer (score 4):

I give an answer here using only elementary algebraic geometry.

We know that the Grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}(2,5)$ is defined by $5$ linearly independent quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^9$ and $V(5)$  can  be viewed  as defined by $5$ linearly independent quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^6$.

Given a point $p=[1,0,\dots,0]\in X$ for  $X\subset \mathbb{P}^6$  defined by $Q_i, 1\leq i\leq 5$, where $Q_i$ are homogeneous of degree $2$.
Write $$Q_i= q_{i,2}(x_1,\dots, x_6)+ x_0 q_{i,1}(x_1,\dots, x_6)$$
with $q_{i,k}$  homogeneous of degree $k$.

I claim that
there there is a line contained in $X$ passing through $p$ if and only if $$q_{i,k}=0, \quad 1\leq i \leq 5, k=1,2 \quad (*)$$ have  a common zero in $\mathbb{P}^{5}=\mathbb{P}(k[x_1,\dots x_6])$.  To see this, note that given a common zero $[a_1,a_2,\dots,a_6]\in\mathbb{P}^{5}$, the line joining $p$ to $[0, a_1,a_2,\dots,a_6]$ is contained in $X$ and the line joining $[1,0,\dots,0]$ and $[1,-a_1,\dots,-a_n]$ is the same as the  line joining $[1,0,\dots,0]$ and $[0, a_1,\dots,a_n]$.

Since $Q_i$ are linearly independent, we see that the linear part $q_{i,1}, 1\leq i\leq 5$ are linearly independent.  By the geometric version of Krull’s Principal Ideal Theorem[11.3.2, Vakil’s notes], the dimension of the subvariety in $\mathbb{P}^5$ defined by $(*)$ is $\leq 0$.  This means $(*)$ has finitely many common zeros, that is, there are at most finitely many lines passing through a given point.

Now back to $X=V(5)$, as suggested by Enrico in the comment. We take $3$ hyperplanes ''general enough'' to get explicit defining equations of $V(5)$. Consider the Plucker coordinate $w_{ij}$ in $\mathbb{P}^9$,  take $w_{12}=w_{34}$, $w_{13}=w_{45}$, $w_{23}=w_{15}$, the defining equations for $V(5)$ are

\begin{cases}
w_{34}^2-w_{45}w_{24}+w_{14}w_{15}=0\\
w_{45}^2-w_{14}w_{35}+w_{15}w_{34}=0\\
w_{15}^2-w_{45}w_{25}+w_{34}w_{35}=0\\
w_{15}w_{45}-w_{24}w_{35}+w_{25}w_{34}=0\\
w_{34}w_{45}-w_{14}w_{25}+w_{15}w_{24}=0
\end{cases}

By the above argument, choose $p$ to be the point with the only nonzero entry $w_{ij}$ for $\{i,j\}\neq \{3,4\},\{4,5\},\{1,5\}$ we can have some lines. For example,
we can find two nonintersecting lines: one joining $[ x_{14}=1,x_{ij}=0]$ and $[x_{12}=1,x_{ij}=0]$, the other joining $[ x_{24}=1,x_{ij}=0]$ and $[ x_{25}=1,x_{ij}=0]$. This has solved the question.

---

**Remark.**
Suppose we are given the fact that for every point, there is at least one line passing through it, we can show that the subvariety in $\operatorname{Gr}(2,7)$ characterising lines on $V(5)$ has dimension $ 2$.  Consider the following incidence correspondence, as we have discussed above, for any $p\in V(5)$ the fibre $\operatorname{pr}_1^{-1} (p)$ has dimension $0$.

[image]

By Upper Semicontinuity of Fibre Dimension, we have $\operatorname{dim} \Phi= \operatorname{dim} V(5)=3$. Take a line $l\in V(5)$,  $\operatorname{dim}pr_2^{-1}([l])=1$, by Upper Semicontinuity again, $\operatorname{dim}\Phi -\operatorname{dim} pr_2\Phi = 1$, $\operatorname{dim} pr_2\Phi = 2$. We conclude that the subvariety of $\operatorname{Grass}(2,7)$ characterising lines on $V(5)$ has dimension $ 2$.

A stronger result than $\operatorname{dim }pr_2\Phi= 2$ is that the Hilbert scheme of lines on $V(5)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$ as in Sasha's answer and the reference is [Theorem 1, 2].  And the number of lines passing through a point is $3$ when counted with multiplicity [P.26, 1].

$[1]$
*Takagi, Hiromichi; Zucconi, Francesco*, [**Geometries of lines and conics on the quintic del Pezzo 3-fold and its application to varieties of power sums**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1331222846), Mich. Math. J. 61, No. 1, 19-62 (2012). [ZBL1262.14048](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1262.14048).

$[2]$*Furushima, Mikio; Nakayama, Noboru*, [**The family of lines on the Fano threefold (V_ 5)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0027763000001719), Nagoya Math. J. 116, 111-122 (1989). [ZBL0731.14025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0731.14025).